# Problems with \rowcolors and booktabs

Tags: color, tabularx, multirow, booktabs

I've got few tables created with few packages included `booktabs` where I use the command `\rowcolors` from the `xcolor` package. But in the last I notice that the colour is *wider* that the lines of the same table. Since the way to create the tables and the packages used in all are the same I don't know what could happen. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,paper=letter,headings=big,bibliography=totoc,DIV=8]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=true,draft=false}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[single=false,macros=false,xspace=false]{acro}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[defaultsans]{opensans}
\usepackage{array,multirow,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\poise{P}
\DeclareSIUnit\stokes{St}
%\DeclareSIUnit\radian{rad}
\DeclareSIUnit\dyna{dyn}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}   
\centering
\rowcolors{2}{}{lightgray!20}
\begin{tabularx}{3.4in}{@{} CS[table-format=4.4] @{}}             
\toprule
Propiedades materiales en la media & Valor \\ 
\midrule 
$c_M$      & \SI{3.0}{[\kilo\pascal]} \\
$k_{1_M}$  & \SI{2.3632}{[\kilo\pascal]} \\
$k_{2_M}$  & \num{0.8393} \\ 
$\beta_M$  & \ang{29.0} \\
$\kappa_M$ & \SI{1000}{[\mega\pascal]}\\
\midrule 
Propiedades materiales en la adventicia & Valor \\
\midrule
$c_A$      & \SI{0.3}{[\kilo\pascal]} \\
$k_{1_A}$  & \SI{0.5620}{[\kilo\pascal]} \\
$k_{2_A}$  & \num{0.7112} \\ 
$\beta_A$  & \ang{62.0} \\
$\kappa_A$ & \SI{1000}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}            
\caption[Parámetros materiales de la arteria]{Parámetros materiales de la arteria en sus dos túnicas externas: media y adventicia.}
\label{taula:param}
%\setfloatalignment{t}
\end{table}

\begin{table}   
\centering
\rowcolors{2}{}{lightgray!20}
\begin{tabularx}{3.2in}{@{} lYS[table-format=4.4] @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Propiedades materiales} & Valor \\ 
\midrule 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{{\footnotesize Sangre}}}
& $\rho_s$   & \SI{1060}{[\kilo\gram\per\metre^3]} \\
& $\mu_{s}$  & \SI{3.8e-6}{[\metre^2\per\second]} \\ 
\midrule
\rowcolor{white} \multicolumn{3}{c}{Modelo hiperelástico de Mooney-Rivlin}\\
\midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{{\footnotesize Arteria}}}
& $C_1$  & \SI{0.020}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
& $C_2$  & \SI{0.003}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
& $C_3$  & \SI{0.175}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
& $C_4$  & \SI{0.090}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
& $C_5$  & \SI{0}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
& $C_6$  & \SI{0}{[\mega\pascal]} \\          
\midrule 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Modelo hiperelástico de Mooney-Rivlin}\\
\midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{{\footnotesize Placa}}}
& $C_1$  & \SI{-0.452}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
& $C_2$  & \SI{0.510}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
& $C_3$  & \SI{0.101}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
& $C_4$  & \SI{1.256}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
& $C_5$  & \SI{0}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
& $C_6$  & \SI{0.301}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}            
\caption[Parámetros materiales de la sangre, arteria y placa]{Parámetros materiales de la sangre, arteria y placa que los definen como materiales para COMSOL.}
\label{taula:sangue}
\end{table}     
\end{document}
```

Both tables have the same problem, but the second one has a difficult more: I try to add a column with text rotated 90º, but I don't know how to fit it for use the same colour scheme without cover with the colour part of that rotated column... if it is possible.

[image: Result from the MWE]

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at the [guide for how to minimalize your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,paper=letter,headings=big,bibliography=totoc,DIV=8]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=true,draft=false}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[single=false,macros=false,xspace=false]{acro}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[defaultsans]{opensans}
\usepackage{array,multirow,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\poise{P}
\DeclareSIUnit\stokes{St}
%\DeclareSIUnit\radian{rad}
\DeclareSIUnit\dyna{dyn}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\rowcolors{2}{}{lightgray!20}
\begin{tabularx}{3.4in}{@{\kern\tabcolsep}CS[table-format=4.4]<{\kern\tabcolsep}}
\toprule
Propiedades materiales en la media & Valor \\
\midrule
$c_M$      & \SI{3.0}{[\kilo\pascal]} \\
$k_{1_M}$  & \SI{2.3632}{[\kilo\pascal]} \\
$k_{2_M}$  & \num{0.8393} \\
$\beta_M$  & \ang{29.0} \\
$\kappa_M$ & \SI{1000}{[\mega\pascal]}\\
\midrule
Propiedades materiales en la adventicia & Valor \\
\midrule
$c_A$      & \SI{0.3}{[\kilo\pascal]} \\
$k_{1_A}$  & \SI{0.5620}{[\kilo\pascal]} \\
$k_{2_A}$  & \num{0.7112} \\
$\beta_A$  & \ang{62.0} \\
$\kappa_A$ & \SI{1000}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption[Parámetros materiales de la arteria]{Parámetros materiales de la arteria en sus dos túnicas externas: media y adventicia.}
\label{taula:param}
%\setfloatalignment{t}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\rowcolors{2}{}{lightgray!20}
\begin{tabularx}{3.2in}{@{\kern\tabcolsep} lYS[table-format=4.4]<{\kern\tabcolsep}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Propiedades materiales} & Valor \\
\midrule
\cellcolor{lightgray!20}               %%% remove this if you don't want
 & $\rho_s$   & \SI{1060}{[\kilo\gram\per\metre^3]} \\
\multirow{-2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{{\cellcolor{lightgray!20}\footnotesize Sangre}}}& $\mu_{s}$  & \SI{3.8e-6}{[\metre^2\per\second]} \\
\midrule
\rowcolor{white} \multicolumn{3}{c}{Modelo hiperelástico de Mooney-Rivlin}\\
\midrule
\cellcolor{lightgray!20}
\cellcolor{lightgray!20}& $C_1$  & \SI{0.020}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
\cellcolor{lightgray!20}& $C_2$  & \SI{0.003}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
\cellcolor{lightgray!20}& $C_3$  & \SI{0.175}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
\cellcolor{lightgray!20}& $C_4$  & \SI{0.090}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
\cellcolor{lightgray!20}& $C_5$  & \SI{0}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
\multirow{-6}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{{\footnotesize Arteria}}}& $C_6$  & \SI{0}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Modelo hiperelástico de Mooney-Rivlin}\\
\midrule
\cellcolor{lightgray!20}
\cellcolor{lightgray!20}& $C_1$  & \SI{-0.452}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
\cellcolor{lightgray!20}& $C_2$  & \SI{0.510}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
\cellcolor{lightgray!20}& $C_3$  & \SI{0.101}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
\cellcolor{lightgray!20}& $C_4$  & \SI{1.256}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
\cellcolor{lightgray!20}& $C_5$  & \SI{0}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
\multirow{-6}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{{\cellcolor{lightgray!20}\footnotesize Placa}}}& $C_6$  & \SI{0.301}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption[Parámetros materiales de la sangre, arteria y placa]{Parámetros materiales de la sangre, arteria y placa que los definen como materiales para COMSOL.}
\label{taula:sangue}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have introduced some `\kern` in the first and last columns. To have rotated text over the color, I have moved `\multirow` to the last line with negative number of `rows like

```
\multirow{-2}{*}....
```

And last, I have used `\cellcolor` to fill just one cell at suitable places. If you don't want to color the entire first column that has multi rows, remove the `\cellcolor{lightgray!20}` from those cells like

```
\midrule
& $C_1$  & \SI{0.020}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
& $C_2$  & \SI{0.003}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
& $C_3$  & \SI{0.175}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
& $C_4$  & \SI{0.090}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
& $C_5$  & \SI{0}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
\multirow{-6}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{{\footnotesize Arteria}}}& $C_6$  & \SI{0}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
\midrule
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Wow, it looks great, thanks a lot, `\cellcolor` was the option I need, let me study the code and apply it to my document.

Comment: I included a new third table with problems, what do you suggest me in this case?

Comment: @Aradnix By `\rowcolors{5}{}{lightgray!20}` coloring starts from rwo number 5. In your table row number 5 is starting with contents `0 & {-}    & {-}    & 1.00 & -   \\`. So every thing is working as per rule. If you want coloring to start from the row `4 & 4.10 & 10.9 & 0.32 & 193 \\` , use `\rowcolors{9}{}{lightgray!20}` since it is 9th row. Also better use braces around `-`. Hope I didn't miss anything.

Comment: line or row 5 is right for start colouring table, but when I try to use C or Y column type starts from row 1 instead of 5. That's strange. I'll add brackets to the dashes, thanks.

Comment: @Aradnix I got it now. I think it deserves to be a separate question. As a short cut, you may be `hiderowcolors` and `\showrowcolors` from `xcolor` for the time being.

Comment: ok I'll post it as a different question later, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` have built-in tools to color rows, columns and cells and it is directly compatible with `booktabs`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{cS[table-format=4.4]}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolors{2}{}{lightgray!20}
\Body
  \toprule
  Propiedades materiales en la media & Valor \\
  \midrule
  $c_M$      & \SI{3.0}{[\kilo\pascal]} \\
  $k_{1_M}$  & \SI{2.3632}{[\kilo\pascal]} \\
  $k_{2_M}$  & \num{0.8393} \\
  $\beta_M$  & \ang{29.0} \\
  $\kappa_M$ & \SI{1000}{[\mega\pascal]}\\
  \midrule
  Propiedades materiales en la adventicia & Valor \\
  \midrule
  $c_A$      & \SI{0.3}{[\kilo\pascal]} \\
  $k_{1_A}$  & \SI{0.5620}{[\kilo\pascal]} \\
  $k_{2_A}$  & \num{0.7112} \\
  $\beta_A$  & \ang{62.0} \\
  $\kappa_A$ & \SI{1000}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption[Parámetros materiales de la arteria]{Parámetros materiales de la arteria en sus dos túnicas externas: media y adventicia.}
\label{taula:param}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the first code]

For the second table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{NiceTabular}{llS[table-format=4.4]}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolors{2-3}{}{lightgray!20}[cols={2,3}]
  \rowcolors{5-10}{lightgray!20}{}[cols={2,3}]
  \rowcolors{12-17}{lightgray!20}{}[cols={2,3},restart]
\Body
  \toprule
  & Propiedades materiales & Valor \\
  \midrule
  \Block{2-1}{\rotate \footnotesize Sangre}
   & $\rho_s$   & \SI{1060}{[\kilo\gram\per\metre^3]} \\
   & $\mu_{s}$  & \SI{3.8e-6}{[\metre^2\per\second]} \\
  \midrule
  \Block{1-3}{Modelo hiperelástico de Mooney-Rivlin}\\
  \midrule
  \Block{6-1}{\rotate\footnotesize Arteria}
  & $C_1$  & \SI{0.020}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
  & $C_2$  & \SI{0.003}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
  & $C_3$  & \SI{0.175}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
  & $C_4$  & \SI{0.090}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
  & $C_5$  & \SI{0}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
  & $C_6$  & \SI{0}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
  \midrule
  \Block{1-3}{Modelo hiperelástico de Mooney-Rivlin}\\
  \midrule
  \Block{6-1}{\rotate \footnotesize Placa}
  & $C_1$  & \SI{-0.452}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
  & $C_2$  & \SI{0.510}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
  & $C_3$  & \SI{0.101}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
  & $C_4$  & \SI{1.256}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
  & $C_5$  & \SI{0}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
  & $C_6$  & \SI{0.301}{[\mega\pascal]} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption[Parámetros materiales de la sangre, arteria y placa]{Parámetros materiales de la sangre, arteria y placa que los definen como materiales para COMSOL.}
\label{taula:sangue}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code (second table)]