# Problems for coloring tables using booktabs and xcolor

Tags: color, siunitx, tabularx, booktabs

Well, recently I posted [a question related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209574/problems-with-rowcolors-and-booktabs/209581?noredirect=1#comment490026_209581) here. Thanks to the solution suggested by Harish Kumar I could fix the two tables posted at first. Later I tried to apply the solution to a new third table. This table is like two tables in one, so I try to start the colouring of the rows until the 5th row for let the headers in white. The problem is that I can't get a nice result using the columntypes `C` or `Y` defined in the preamble, if I use them again I've got colour blocks wider than rulers but also `\rowcolor` starts not in the 5th but in the 1st row. Also I'm not sure the column `S` would be the best choice for this table, but the idea is to align the contents using the decimal mark (point).

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,paper=letter,headings=big,bibliography=totoc,DIV=8]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=true,draft=false}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{array,multirow,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\poise{P}
\DeclareSIUnit\stokes{St}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!tb]
\caption[Componentes de Fourier y sus correspondientes valores de $\alpha$]{Componentes de Fourier y los valores correspondientes del parámetro adimensional $\alpha$ para formas de onda de flujo registradas a partir de las arterias carótidas y femorales comunes de un sujeto joven. Los valores de $v_p$ se han normalizado a $v_0$, y el ángulo $\varphi_p$ está dada en grados desde un punto de partida arbitrario.}
\label{tab:fouriercomp}
\centering
\rowcolors{5}{}{lightgray!20}
\begin{tabularx}{3.1in}{@{\kern\tabcolsep}CCS[table-format=2.1]S[table-format=1.2]Y<{\kern\tabcolsep}}          
\toprule
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Femoral común}\\
\multicolumn{5}{p{3.1in}}{(diámetro: \SI{8.4}{\milli\metre}; frecuencia cardíaca: 62 latidos/min;} \\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{viscosidad: \SI{0.038}{\stokes})}\\ %\hline
\midrule
Armónico & Frecuencia & $\alpha$ & $v_p$ & $\varphi_p$ \\
\midrule
0 & {-}  & {-}  & 1.00 & {-} \\
1 & 1.03 &  5.5 & 1.89 &  32 \\
2 & 2.05 &  7.7 & 2.49 &  85 \\
3 & 3.08 &  9.5 & 1.28 & 156 \\
4 & 4.10 & 10.9 & 0.32 & 193 \\
5 & 5.13 & 12.2 & 0.27 & 133 \\
6 & 6.15 & 13.4 & 0.32 & 155 \\
7 & 7.18 & 14.5 & 0.28 & 195 \\
8 & 8.21 & 15.5 & 0.01 & 310 \\
\midrule
\rowcolor{white} \multicolumn{5}{C}{Carótida común}\\
\rowcolor{white}\multicolumn{5}{Y}{(diámetro: \SI{6.0}{\milli\metre}; frecuencia cardíaca: 62 latidos/min;}\\
\rowcolor{white} \multicolumn{5}{Y}{viscosidad: \SI{0.038}{\stokes})}\\ %\hline
\midrule \rowcolor{white}
Armónico & Frecuencia & $\alpha$ & $v_p$ & $\varphi_p$ \\
\midrule
0 & {-}  & {-}  & 1.00 & {-} \\
1 & 1.03 &  3.9 & 0.33 &  74 \\
2 & 2.05 &  5.5 & 0.24 &  79 \\
3 & 3.08 &  6.8 & 0.24 & 124 \\
4 & 4.10 &  7.8 & 0.12 & 146 \\
5 & 5.13 &  8.7 & 0.11 & 147 \\
6 & 6.15 &  9.6 & 0.13 & 179 \\
7 & 7.18 & 10.3 & 0.06 & 233 \\
8 & 8.21 & 12.4 & 0.04 & 218 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}      
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Since the headers of both tables are almost the same, I should the different approaches I tried before without nice results.

[image]

Comment: Are all of those package necessary to reproduce the problem? If say, you use the default fonts, does it work fine? If not, please make your code into an MWE by removing the ones which are irrelevant.

Comment: @cfr I try to simplify the MWE, I removed a lot of packages, but since this is not an essay for curiosity but part of a bigger document I use them for reproduce the exact layout of the image and avoid another possible problems. I don't know what's wrong with the font, it makes impossible to run the MWE?

Comment: @Aradnix The problem is that we have to check if the font is the problem, while you could do that easily for us. You have to minimize as long as you can in order to pass less work to us. Btw., your example does not result in your screenshot for me.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explain me, I'll keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I propose to simplify your table? You do not need all these special columns in my eyes. The trick used here is to reset the row numbers which are used by the `table` option of `xcolor`. The credits for this go to Heiko Oberdiek.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,paper=letter,DIV=8]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=true}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\stokes{St}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{c@rownum}{%
    \let\c@rownum\rownum
}{}
\@ifundefined{therownum}{%
    \def\therownum{\@arabic\rownum}%
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h!tb]
        \centering%
        \caption[Componentes de Fourier y sus correspondientes valores de $\alpha$]{Componentes de Fourier y los valores correspondientes del parámetro adimensional $\alpha$ para formas de onda de flujo registradas a partir de las arterias carótidas y femorales comunes de un sujeto joven. Los valores de $v_p$ se han normalizado a $v_0$, y el ángulo $\varphi_p$ está dada en grados desde un punto de partida arbitrario.}%
        \label{tab:fouriercomp}%    
        \rowcolors{4}{gray!20}{}%
        \begin{tabular}{%
                S[table-format=1.0]
                S[table-format=1.2]
                S[table-format=2.1]
                S[table-format=1.2]
                S[table-format=3.0]
                }          
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textsc{Femoral común}} \\
            \multicolumn{5}{p{2.4in}}{(diámetro: \SI{8.4}{\milli\metre}; frecuencia cardíaca: \SI{62}{latidos\per\minute}; viscosidad: \SI{0.038}{\stokes})} \\ 
            \midrule
            {Armónico} & {Frecuencia} & $\alpha$ & $v_p$ & $\varphi_p$ \\
            \midrule
            0 & {-}  & {-}  & 1.00 & {-} \\
            1 & 1.03 &  5.5 & 1.89 &  32 \\
            2 & 2.05 &  7.7 & 2.49 &  85 \\
            3 & 3.08 &  9.5 & 1.28 & 156 \\
            4 & 4.10 & 10.9 & 0.32 & 193 \\
            5 & 5.13 & 12.2 & 0.27 & 133 \\
            6 & 6.15 & 13.4 & 0.32 & 155 \\
            7 & 7.18 & 14.5 & 0.28 & 195 \\
            8 & 8.21 & 15.5 & 0.01 & 310 {\setcounter{rownum}{0}} \\
            \midrule
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textsc{Carótida común}}\\
            \multicolumn{5}{p{2.4in}}{(diámetro: \SI{6.0}{\milli\metre}; frecuencia cardíaca: \SI{62}{latidos\per\minute}; viscosidad: \SI{0.038}{\stokes})} \\
            \midrule
            {Armónico} & {Frecuencia} & $\alpha$ & $v_p$ & $\varphi_p$ \\
            \midrule
            0 & {-}  & {-}  & 1.00 & {-} \\
            1 & 1.03 &  3.9 & 0.33 &  74 \\
            2 & 2.05 &  5.5 & 0.24 &  79 \\
            3 & 3.08 &  6.8 & 0.24 & 124 \\
            4 & 4.10 &  7.8 & 0.12 & 146 \\
            5 & 5.13 &  8.7 & 0.11 & 147 \\
            6 & 6.15 &  9.6 & 0.13 & 179 \\
            7 & 7.18 & 10.3 & 0.06 & 233 \\
            8 & 8.21 & 12.4 & 0.04 & 218 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}      
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]