# Adjust table widths, spacing and color

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment, rowcolor

I have a question regarding tables in Latex. I tried to find a solution now for two hours, but couldn't fix all my problems in one code. So I found single solutions for everything, but couldn't bring them together.

I added some code and a picture to explain the table I want to have in the end. Unfortunately there are some points I don't like and hope someone can help me. I would like to have:

1. No white colored spaces above and below the lines
2. I would like to adjust the spacing between the lines generally
3. The table shall have exactly the width of my text
4. I want to adjust the width of all columns by my self specifying in percent
5. I want in some cases have the first column colored differently
6. I want the text in my head row to be white
7. I need to use footnotes in the table. It doesn't matter if they are explained below the table or at the page bottom.
8. I want to change the horizontal alignment of the cells with numbers in it to right align.
9. I'm open to the package to use, so if needed feel free to propose another one :-)

Thank you very much for your help.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{rgb}{0.80784, 0.86667, 0.90196} %dunkelblau
\definecolor{Lightgray}{rgb}{0.9176, 0.95, 0.95686} %hellblau
\definecolor{Akzent}{rgb}{0.6627, 0.63529, 0.55294} %akzentfarbe

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{.15\linewidth} p{.1\linewidth} p{.2\linewidth} p{.2\linewidth} X}
    \toprule
    \rowcolor{Akzent}
    Category & Size & Maximum Takeoff Weight (MTOW) (kg) & Normal Operating Altitude (ft) & Airspeed (m/s)\\
    \midrule
    \rowcolor{Gray}
    Group 1 & Small & 0 - 20 & < 1,200 AGL & < 100\\
    \rowcolor{Lightgray}
    Group 2 & Medium & 21 - 55 & < 3500 & < 250\footnote{Explanation}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Table}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! (1) Have a look at [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209718/124577), (3) It should have according to your option, (4) you already do (except last column), (5) have a look at `\cellcolor`, (6) see (1), (7) there is a `\makesavenoteenv` (package `\footnote`), (8) use a `>{\raggedleft}p{.1\linewidth}`. These are just suggestions at first glance and may not work out perfectly, but see it as starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is something that looks nicer, though far from perfect. For *point 1*, it's due to the padding that `booktabs` adds above and/or below its rules. So I had to suppress this padding, and replace it with `\extrarowsep`, for `\belowrulesep` and with a rule of the same thickness as below, and same colour as the row colour, for `aboverulesep`. To ease doing  so, I defined a `\colourpadding` command, with one argument, the colour one wishes.

There might have been a simpler solution with the `\makegapedcells` command  from `makecell`. Unfortunately, it appears not to be compatible with colouring tables.

*Point 2:* There are several ways to do that. The simplest is changing the value of `arraystretch`. It has the inconvenience that  for bib values, the contents  is no more centred in its cell. If necessary, you can use `\arraystretch=some length`, which adds a length at the top of cells in each row. Two last solutions: `makecell` has two commands: `\setcellgapes{some length}` and `\makegapedcells}`, which adds a fixed length at the top and bottom of all cells in a table. It does not work here. Last solution: `cellspace` defines *minimal* distances between the top of a cell and the line above (or the bottom of the row above), and between the bottom of a cell and the line below.

*Point 3*. It's done with `tabularx`. I preferred to use 3 `X` columns, and  slightly change the first two columns widths.

*Point 4:* I don't see what you want exactly.

*Point 5:* I think you would have to colour differently each cell of the first column, via `\cellcolor`.

*Point 6* is done.

*Point 7:* Footnotes can be put at the bottom of the table with the `threeparttable` package (ot `threeparttablex` for long tables). For usual footnote, you have the `tablefootnote` package.

*Point 8*. To have numbers right-aligned, you can add `>{\raggedleft}` to the column specifier, or choose the `S` column type (load `siunitx`).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e, eqparbox}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}m{#1} <{\hspace*{-1pt}}}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{Gray}{rgb}{0.80784, 0.86667, 0.90196} %dunkelblau
\definecolor{Lightgray}{rgb}{0.9176, 0.95, 0.95686} %hellblau
\definecolor{Akzent}{rgb}{0.6627, 0.63529, 0.55294} %akzentfarbe
\newcommand{\whitehead}{\bfseries\color{white}}

\newcommand\colourpadding[1]{\addlinespace[-1pt]\arrayrulecolor{#1}\midrule[6pt]\arrayrulecolor{black}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{table}
\centering
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\setlength\doublerulesep{0pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{M{.12 \linewidth}M{.08\linewidth}*{3}{X}} \toprule
    \rowcolor{Akzent}
 \whitehead Category & \whitehead Size &\whitehead Maximum Takeoff Weight (MTOW) (kg) &\whitehead Normal Operating Altitude (ft) &\whitehead Airspeed (m/s)\\
    \colourpadding{Akzent}
        \midrule
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Group 1 & Small & 0 – 20 & \eqmakebox[A][l]{< 1,200 AGL} & < 100\\
    \colourpadding{Gray}
        \rowcolor{Lightgray}
        Group 2 & Medium & 21 – 55 & \eqmakebox[A][l]{< 3500} & < 250\rlap{\footnote{Explanation}}\\
\colourpadding{Lightgray}
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Bernhard, thank you very much for this very helpful answer. The table looks nearly as I intended. Just a few questions regarding the column width & alignment.
P4: Let's say for any reason I want to design the table such, that all columns are 20% (of textwidth) wide. How could I do that (or any other distribution of the width). Do you understand my question now? Sorry for my english :-)

Do you know a website with a good overview about the cell specifiers (M, X, S, l, c, ..), for me as beginner it's a bit of an overkill and I think many question could be answered by knowledge of them :-)

Comment: This [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) gives  the essentials, I think. Missing: some specific packages like `siunitx` which powerful tools for columns of numbers, `makecell` (line breaking in  `l, r` or `c` cells) and `ltablex` (functionalities of `longtable` in `tabularx`). For you precise question (equal width columns), I would use `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{5}{X}}`.  `X` is a `\p{length}` column type, with `length`  calculated by the package so the total width is `\linewidth`. You can see details on how to customise `X` in the package documentation.

Answer (score 1):

With exploit `boldline` from *Shipunov* bundle for line width and `celspace` for additional vertical space in cells:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
  \definecolor{Gray}{rgb}{0.80784, 0.86667, 0.90196} %dunkelblau
  \definecolor{Lightgray}{rgb}{0.9176, 0.95, 0.95686} %hellblau
  \definecolor{Akzent}{rgb}{0.6627, 0.63529, 0.55294} %akzentfarbe
\usepackage{tabularx}
  \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{cellspace}
  \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
  \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
  \addparagraphcolumntypes{C}
\usepackage{boldline}% part of Shipunov bundle

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\newcommand\whitehead[1]{\textcolor{white}{\bfseries #1}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Sl
                                  l
                             *{3}{C}
                                }
    \hlineB{2}  % <-- defined in the package "boldline", thicknes=2pt
    \rowcolor{gray}
\whitehead{Category}
    &   \whitehead{Size}
        &    \whitehead{Maximum Take-off Weight (MTOW) (kg)}
            &   \whitehead{Normal Operating Altitude (ft)}
                &   \whitehead{Airspeed (m/s)}              \\
    \hlineB{1}
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
        Group 1 & Small  &  0 – 20 & < 1,200 AGL    & < 100 \\
    \rowcolor{gray!20}
        Group 2 & Medium & 21 – 55 & < 3500         & < 250 \rlap{\footnote{Explanation}}\\
    \hlineB{2}
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{Table}
\end{table}
    \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. The main drawback of `{NiceTabular}` is that it can't be broken (like `longtable`).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\definecolor{Gray}{rgb}{0.80784, 0.86667, 0.90196} %dunkelblau
\definecolor{Lightgray}{rgb}{0.9176, 0.95, 0.95686} %hellblau
\definecolor{Akzent}{rgb}{0.6627, 0.63529, 0.55294} %akzentfarbe

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit=2pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{m[l]{.12 \linewidth}m[l]{.08\linewidth}*{3}{X[m,c]}}[colortbl-like]
\toprule
\rowcolor{Akzent}
\RowStyle[color=white,bold]{\sffamily}
 Category & Size & Maximum Takeoff Weight (MTOW) (kg) & Normal Operating Altitude (ft) & Airspeed (m/s)\\
\midrule
\rowcolor{Gray}
Group 1 & Small & 0 -- 20 & < 1,200 AGL & < 100\\
\rowcolor{Lightgray}
Group 2 & Medium & 21 -- 55 & < 3500 & < 250\tabularnote{Explanation}\\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]