# How to fit a table with long header cells in "S"-type columns?

Tags: tables, siunitx, best-practices, tabularx

Well fit tables in LaTeX is hard for me, and I don't know if there is a manual with good practices about it. I need to create a table with S columns contending numbers, but the header of those columns are very long and I can't find a way to fit it into the page with the tricks learned here.

My MWE could be something like:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=letter,headings=small,bibliography=totoc,DIV=9,headsepline=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{array,multirow,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
%\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
%\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    output-decimal-marker = {,}, 
    range-units = brackets,
    list-final-separator = { \translate{and} },
    list-pair-separator = { \translate{and} },
    range-phrase = { \translate{to (numerical range)} },
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\providetranslation [ to = Spanish ]
{ to~(numerical~range) } { a }%substitute the right word here
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{Capacidad de generación eléctrica en México}
    \label{tab:CGE}
    \centering

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l S S[table-format=6.2] S[table-format=3.2]@{}}
    \toprule
        & \textbf{Permisos de la CRE} & \textbf{Capacidad de generación de energía} [\si{\giga\watt\hour}] & \textbf{Porcentaje}\\
    \midrule
    % Pública
    \textbf{Energía de generación propia} & & \textbf{169,900.00} & \textbf{42.25} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Pemex} & &  & \\
    \textbf{Autoabastecimiento} & 31 & 2526.40 & 0.61 \\
    \textbf{Cogeneración} & 18 & 7049.04 & 1.75 \\ 
    \textbf{Subtotal} & & 9575.44 & 2.38 \\
    % Privada
    \midrule
    \textbf{Autoabastecimiento} & 486 & 67145.80 & 16.70 \\
    \textbf{Cogeneración} & 109 & 18153.66 & 4.51 \\
    \textbf{Producción independiente} & 30 & 105634.80 & 26.27 \\
    \textbf{Exportación} & 8 & 13295.60 & 3.31 \\
    \textbf{Importación} & 44 & 2061.30 & 0.51 \\
    \textbf{Pequeña producción} & 178 & 12212.60 & 3.04 \\
    \textbf{Usos Propios Continuos} & 36 & 1523.50 & 0.38 \\
    \textbf{Pemex-Cogeneración} & 1 & 2628.00 & 0.65 \\
    \textbf{Subtotal} & 844 & 222655.26 & 55.37 \\
    \textbf{Total CRE} & 892 & 232230.70 & 57.75 \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Total} & 892 & 402130.14 & 100 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

As you can see my first issue is to fit the table inside the page. The second one is put in boldface the units in the title row. A third issue is to add a column in the left side of the table to specify the public and private generation, bit I think that could be easy to solve after the first one.

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I didn't found an answer in the questions I was reading before to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is the `makecell` package, which allows for line breaks in cells, and a common formatting of column heads. Added a small vertical padding in rows and replaced the `l` column with `X`. Finally I took the liberty to correct some inconsistencies in the formatting of boldface numbers in the second row.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=letter,headings=small,bibliography=totoc,DIV=9,headsepline=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{array,multirow,tabularx,ragged2e, booktabs}
%\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
%\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\sisetup{
output-decimal-marker = {,},
range-units = brackets,
list-final-separator = { \translate{and} },
list-pair-separator = { \translate{and} },
range-phrase = { \translate{to (numerical range)} },
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\providetranslation [ to = Spanish ]
{ to~(numerical~range) } { a }%substitute the right word here
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\setcellgapes{1.5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering\makegapedcells
  \caption{Capacidad de generación eléctrica en México}
  \label{tab:CGE}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries\RaggedRight}X S S[table-format=6.2] S[table-format=2.2]@{}}
    \addlinespace
    \toprule
    \addlinespace[-0.3ex]
    & {\thead{Permisos\\ de la CRE}} & {\thead{Capacidad de \\generación de\\ energía (\si{\giga\watt\hour})}}
    & {\thead{Porcentaje}}\\[-0.6ex]
    \midrule
    % Pública
    Energía de generación propia & & \textbf{169\,900,00} & \textbf{42,25} \\
    \midrule
    Pemex & & & \\
    Autoabastecimiento & 31 & 2526.40 & 0.61 \\
    Cogeneración & 18 & 7049.04 & 1.75 \\
    Subtotal & & 9575.44 & 2.38 \\
    % Privada
    \midrule
    Autoabastecimiento & 486 & 67145.80 & 16.70 \\
    Cogeneración & 109 & 18153.66 & 4.51 \\
    Producción independiente & 30 & 105634.80 & 26.27 \\
    Exportación & 8 & 13295.60 & 3.31 \\
    Importación & 44 & 2061.30 & 0.51 \\
    Pequeña producción & 178 & 12212.60 & 3.04 \\
    Usos Propios Continuos & 36 & 1523.50 & 0.38 \\
    Pemex-Cogeneración & 1 & 2628.00 & 0.65 \\
    Subtotal & 844 & 222655.26 & 55.37 \\
    Total CRE & 892 & 232230.70 & 57.75 \\
    \midrule
    Total & 892 & 402130.14 & 100 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thakns for the suggestions and the solution. I want to add a narrow column with text rotated 90° in the left side similar to [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209574/problems-with-rowcolors-and-booktabs) but without colouring the table. How to specify it before the `{\bfseries\RaggedRight}X`?

Comment: @Aradnix: Do you mean some multirow with rotated text along the whole height of the table? Could you explain with more details?

Comment: Yes, in fact I want to use multirow with 90° CCW rotated text for specify the public and private energy production in that table. I was thinking to add that row in each subtotal row. But I'm not sure how to specify that column. With `l` or `X` I Have an error.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use smaller font (if necessary) and put columns header in more lines, something like this:
[image]

For above table I added package `makecell` and put columns header into `theader` from `makecell`:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=letter,headings=small,bibliography=totoc,DIV=9,headsepline=true]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
    \usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
    \usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
    \usepackage{xspace}
    \usepackage{xkeyval}
    \usepackage{array,multirow,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
    \usepackage{makecell}% added
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}% added
%\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
%\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{colortbl}
    \usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    output-decimal-marker = {,},
    range-units = brackets,
    list-final-separator = { \translate{and} },
    list-pair-separator = { \translate{and} },
    range-phrase = { \translate{to (numerical range)} },
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\providetranslation [ to = Spanish ]
{ to~(numerical~range) } { a }%substitute the right word here
\ExplSyntaxOff

    \usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \small% added
    \caption{Capacidad de generación eléctrica en México}
    \label{tab:CGE}
    \centering

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\bfseries}l S S[table-format=6.2] S[table-format=3.2]}
    \toprule
        &   {\thead{Permisos\\ 
             de la CRE}}
            &   {\thead{Capacidad de\\ generación de \\ 
                       energía [\si{\giga\watt\hour}]}}
                &   {\thead{Porcentaje}}\\
    \midrule
    % Pública
Energía de generación propia
                    & & \textbf{169,900.00} & \textbf{42.25} \\
    \midrule
Pemex               & &  & \\
Autoabastecimiento  & 31 & 2526.40 & 0.61 \\
Cogeneración        & 18 & 7049.04 & 1.75 \\
Subtotal            & & 9575.44 & 2.38 \\
    % Privada
    \midrule
Autoabastecimiento  & 486 & 67145.80 & 16.70 \\
Cogeneración        & 109 & 18153.66 & 4.51 \\
Producción independiente  & 30 & 105634.80 & 26.27 \\
Exportación         & 8   & 13295.60 & 3.31 \\
Importación         & 44  & 2061.30 & 0.51 \\
Pequeña producción  & 178 & 12212.60 & 3.04 \\
Usos Propios Continuos    & 36 & 1523.50 & 0.38 \\
Pemex-Cogeneración  & 1   & 2628.00 & 0.65 \\
Subtotal            & 844 & 222655.26 & 55.37 \\
Total CRE           & 92  & 232230.70 & 57.75 \\
    \midrule
Total               & 892 & 402130.14 & 100 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

For final form you can play with broken column's header into appropriate number of lines and select other font size.

**Edit**
As @Manuel say in his comment, in the first column can be omited `\textbf{....}` if you in column type you include `>{\bfseries}l`. I now considering this and correct the code above.

Comment: You can put `>{\bfseries} l` in the declaration of columns, and avoid using `\textbf{..}` in each cell of the first column.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to change the font size or abandon the basic `tabularx` structure. All you have to do, really, is to (a) change the column type for the header cells of the first two numeric columns to (a centered version of) the `X` column type, and (b) place curly braces around the right-hand most column header, viz. `\textbf{Porcentaje}`, to tell LaTeX to center its contents.

To unify and simplify the look of the table, I would further suggest you use the `siunitx` option `group-minimum-digits = 4`, that you not bold-face the numbers in first row of the table, and to indent a few entries in the first column (and omit a couple of horizontal lines). Finally, if you specify the type of the first column as `>{\bfseries}l` rather than just as `l`, you needn't type `\textbf` in all subsequent cells of that column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=letter,headings=small,
     bibliography=totoc,DIV=9,headsepline=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{array,multirow,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    output-decimal-marker = {,},
    group-minimum-digits = 4, 
    range-units = brackets,
    list-final-separator = { \translate{and} },
    list-pair-separator = { \translate{and} },
    range-phrase = { \translate{to (numerical range)} },
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\providetranslation [ to = Spanish ]
{ to~(numerical~range) } { a }%substitute the right word here
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{Capacidad de generación eléctrica en México}
    \label{tab:CGE}
    %%\centering  % not needed

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\bfseries}l 
         S[table-format=3.0]
         S[table-format=6.2] 
         S[table-format=3.2] @{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{1}{C}{\textbf{Permisos de la CRE}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{C}{\textbf{Capacidad de generación de energía} [\si{\giga\watt\hour}]} & 
    {\textbf{Porcentaje}}\\
    \midrule
    % Pública
    Energía de generación propia & & 169900.00 &  42.25 \\
    \midrule
    Pemex & &  & \\
    Autoabastecimiento & 31 & 2526.40 & 0.61 \\
    Cogeneración & 18 & 7049.04 & 1.75 \\ 
    \addlinespace
    \quad Subtotal & & 9575.44 & 2.38 \\
    % Privada
    \addlinespace
    Autoabastecimiento & 486 & 67145.80 & 16.70 \\
    Cogeneración & 109 & 18153.66 & 4.51 \\
    Producción independiente & 30 & 105634.80 & 26.27 \\
    Exportación & 8 & 13295.60 & 3.31 \\
    Importación & 44 & 2061.30 & 0.51 \\
    Pequeña producción & 178 & 12212.60 & 3.04 \\
    Usos Propios Continuos & 36 & 1523.50 & 0.38 \\
    Pemex-Cogeneración & 1 & 2628.00 & 0.65 \\
    \addlinespace
    \quad Subtotal & 844 & 222655.26 & 55.37 \\
    \addlinespace
    \quad Total CRE & 892 & 232230.70 & 57.75 \\
    \midrule
    Total & 892 & 402130.14 & 100.00 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Interesting solution, I started with this one for avoid add more packages: Unfortunately the problem with alignment remains. Good trick that of the boldface to the head of the table. I had already seen your recommendation to better align the digits with `group- minimum- digits = 4` . However I have a question: If you see the units at the header of the table, they don't appear in boldface. I think there is a way to change that, but I don't remember what `siunitx` option do it.

Comment: @Aradnix - I must state up front that my personal style is *not* to use **boldface** unless it's absolutely required. (In my own working papers, I sometimes don't even set the section headers in bold!) From my subjective point of view, then, you're already massively overusing boldface in the table. If this were my own table, I wouldn't use any bold-facing *at all*; for sure, I certainly wouldn't show the units in bold. If it were absolutely necessary to provide some specific emphasis, I might italicize the two "Subtotal" strings and the "Total CRE" string.

Comment: I see, I also avoid to use boldface, but this time is not my decision, is something the boss wants. But I'm agree with you, let me change it and present a new layout with less boldface usage. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There is one simple technique using the default `booktabs` package.

```
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} table \\ heading \end{tabular}
```

For example, In your table, the heading 'Permisos de la CRE' can be broken in two lines as:

```
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Permisos \\ de la CRE \end{tabular}
```

This can be done in any rows or columns in a table, not just in heading.

Comment: Your code makes no use of [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs). Why is that?