# rowcolors when space is removed with @{}

Tags: tables, color

When space on either side of a table is removed with `@{}`, then the color added with `\rowcolors` will expand beyond the width of the table. In the [answer provided](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209581/9077) to a similar question, this is fixed by putting `@{\kern\tabcolsep}` instead of `@{}`. But that's equivalent to just removing `@{}` from the code, so I don't really consider that a solution. Is there another way to limit the row colors to the widt of the tabel?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\rowcolors{2}{}{gray}
\begin{tabular}{@{}*4{l}@{}}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\rowcolors{2}{}{gray}
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]}lll>{\columncolor{white}[\tabcolsep][0pt]}l@{}}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you mind explaining your code?

Comment: This also adds a small white vertical line to every cell.

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you will have directly the expected output (and you won't see the thin white lines you see in Ulrike Fisher's answer).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}*4{l}@{}}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolors{2}{}{gray}
\Body
\hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
  5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
  5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]