# remove space between columns in longtabu with rowcolors

Tags: tables, color, rowcolor, ltxtable

I use the `ltxtable` package to create long tables with variable width columns. Using this I want to completely remove the space between to table columns by doing this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth{r@{}l}
    %\taburowcolors{white .. gray}
    \hline
    sth else  & and again \\ \hline
    sth       & blabla \\ 
    else      & stupid\\ 
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

This works fine until I uncomment the `taburowcolors` which enforces some space between the columns and thus cuts some of the text.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You can use `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}`.

Comment: no that doesn't work. It does exactly the same as the `@{}` and cuts some of the text. Also, you can only set it for all columns in a table which is fine for this minimal example, but not in general.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here [colortbl: \rowcolor in tables with \begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35170/colortbl-rowcolor-in-tables-with-begintabularccc): 
adding a `<{\kern\tabcolsep}` before the `@{}` solves the problem.

Another solution was postet here [rowcolors when space is removed with @{}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262375/rowcolors-when-space-is-removed-with). Adding `>{\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]}` after the `@{}` helps as well.